# Relacionamento entre as tabelas

Tags: sql, firebird, join, inner, inner-join

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
TB_ESTOQUE
|COD_PRODUTO|QT_DISPONIVEL|COD_FILIAL|
|  0856322  |      5      |    41    |
|  0856351  |      2      |    41    |
|  0856322  |      9      |    114   |
|  0856720  |      3      |    20    |
|  0856322  |      8      |    128   |
|  0856322  |      12     |     35   |
|  0856322  |      4      |     9    |

TB_FILIAL
|COD_FILIAL|COD_LOCALADM| 
|    41    |    114     |
|    128   |    114     |  
|    114   |    114     |
|    10    |    156     |
|    56    |     12     |
|    35    |     12     |
|    9     |     12     |

TB_PRODUTO
|COD_PRODUTO|DESC_PRODUTO|
|  0856322  | CALCARIO   |
|  0856351  | ZINCO      |
|  0856321  | SEMENTE    |
|  0856720  | INSETICIDA |
|  0856752  | STE SOJA   |

Tabela desejada:
|COD_PRODUTO|DESC_PRODUTO|QT_DISPONIVEL|COD_FILIAL|
|  0856322  |   CALCARIO |       5     |    41    |
|  0856322  |   CALCARIO |       9     |    114   |
|  0856322  |   CALCARIO |       8     |    128   |
```

Estou executando o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT
E.COD_PRODUTO,
P.DESC_PRODUTO,
E.QT_DISPONIVEL,
E.COD_FILIAL
FROM
TB_ESTOQUE E
LEFT JOIN TB_PRODUTO P
ON P.COD_PRODUTO = E.COD_PRODUTO
WHERE
E.COD_PRODUTO = 856322
ORDER BY
P.DESC_PRODUTO
```

Como eu relaciono no SQL a tabela `TB_FILIAL`, filtrando pelo código `COD_LOCALADM`?

Exemplo:

```
... WHERE
    E.COD_PRODUTO = 856322 AND
    TB_FILIAL.COD_LOCALADM = 114
```

Answer (score 4):

Não existe COD_PRODUTO na tabela TB_ESTOQUE segundo o seu exemplo.

Experimente:

```
SELECT
E.PRODUTO,
P.DESC_PRODUTO,
E.QT_DISPONIVEL,
E.COD_FILIAL
FROM
TB_ESTOQUE E, TB_FILIAL F
LEFT JOIN TB_PRODUTO P
ON P.COD_PRODUTO = E.PRODUTO
WHERE
F.COD_FILIAL = E.COD_FILIAL AND
F.COD_LOCALADM = 114 AND
E.PRODUTO = 856322
ORDER BY
P.DESC_PRODUTO
```

Comment: Na verdade existe, eu que coloquei errado.

Comment: A coluna não existe, a coluna que queria era PRODUTO e essa sim existe. Caso eu o tenha ajudado por favor marque a minha resposta como a solução.

Comment: Não ajudou, pois a coluna existe. Vou reformular a minha pergunta.

Comment: A coluna não existe, segundo o que você colocou como exemplo de tabela não existe coluna cod_produto mas sim apenas coluna produto na tabela estoque. Editar a pergunta para corrigir um erro seu no exemplo e dizer que não foi ajudado é incrível. Pessoas como você fazem me deixar de comentar neste site, pedem ajuda, são ajudadas, respondem mal e ainda editam a pergunta. Enfim...

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar a tabela de filial na clausula `FROM` e adicionar os parâmetros para filtragem no `WHERE`, sem muita complicação:

```
SELECT
E.COD_PRODUTO,
P.DESC_PRODUTO,
E.QT_DISPONIVEL,
E.COD_FILIAL
FROM
TB_FILIAL F, 
TB_ESTOQUE E
LEFT JOIN TB_PRODUTO P
ON P.COD_PRODUTO = E.COD_PRODUTO
WHERE
E.COD_PRODUTO = 856322 
AND E.COD_FILIAL = F.COD_FILIAL 
AND F.COD_LOCALADM = 114
ORDER BY
P.DESC_PRODUTO
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o código abaixo, pois acho que não haverá um cenário onde você guarda apenas uma filial no estoque sem produto, ou um produto sem uma filial.

Para o WHERE funcionar, basta apenas colocar as junções, e depois ir chamando Tabela.Campo de acordo com a necessidade.

```
SELECT
  P.COD_PRODUTO,
  P.DESC_PRODUTO,
  E.QT_DISPONIVEL,
  F.COD_FILIAL
FROM TB_ESTOQUE E
INNER JOIN TB_FILIAL F
  ON F.COD_FILIAL = E.COD_FILIAL
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTO P
  ON P.COD_PRODUTO = E.COD_PRODUTO
WHERE P.COD_PRODUTO = 856322
  AND F.COD_FILIAL = 114
ORDER BY
  P.DESC_PRODUTO
```